# How to access SharePoint Online SPFx application in MS Excel?

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, sharepoint-framework, excel-online

I want to develop an SPFx application that can be accessed using MS Excel. When a user opens Excel, our SPFx solution is already ambaded there.

Please share any ideas using which I can achieve the above feature.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the SharePoint Framework can only be used to extend the user interface in SharePoint and Teams.

If you want to build solutions that extend Office applications and interact with content in Office documents, you need to build Office Add-ins. These are are built upon the Office Add-ins platform and use Office JavaScript APIs.

For more information see:

[Office Add-ins platform overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins), and
[Develop Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/develop-overview)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we cannot access SPFx in Excel, the SPFx solutions can only be used to extend **SharePoint and Microsoft Teams**.

More information for reference: [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)

Hope it can help you. Thanks for your understanding and support.

Comment: Do you have any further questions about this thread? If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.